# How to convert a particular dtype object column's field into column of data frame in pandas

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert object type column `page_view_count` fields into column of data frame.

I have a dataframe :

```
    _id                         page_view_count
    568a8c25cac4991645c287ac    {u'main-rating': 2, u'detailed-rating2': 1, u'detailed-rating': 2}      
    568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1    {u'main-rating': 1, u'thank-you': 1, u'detailed-rating2': 1, u'detailed-rating': 1, u'comments': 1}     
    568e5a38b4a797c664143dda    {u'main-rating': 1, u'detailed-rating2': 1, u'detailed-rating': 1}  
    568e5a561ae56e09656bfb99    {u'main-rating': 1, u'detailed-rating': 1}
    56b24c651fd6901e0ac262e4    nan 
    568df45a177e30c6487d3600    {u'main-rating': 1, u'thank-you': 1, u'detailed-rating2': 1, u'detailed-rating': 1, u'comments': 1}
```

I want page_view_count's fields as column of data frame:

```
_id                         main-rating     detailed-rating     detailed-rating2    comments    thank-you
568a8c25cac4991645c287ac    2               1                   1                   nan         nan
568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1    1               1                   1                   1           1
568e5a38b4a797c664143dda    1               1                   1                   nan         nan
568e5a561ae56e09656bfb99    1               1                   nan                 nan         nan
56b24c651fd6901e0ac262e4    nan             nan                 nan                 nan         nan
568df45a177e30c6487d3600    1               1                   1                   1           1
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new dataframe from column `page_view_count` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) column `_id`. Last [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['page_view_count']]).join(df['_id'])
df1 = df1.sort_index(1)
print df1
                            _id  comments  detailed-rating  detailed-rating2  \
0      568a8c25cac4991645c287ac       NaN                2                 1   
1      568cd22e9e82dfc166d7dff1         1                1                 1   
2      568e5a38b4a797c664143dda       NaN                1                 1   
3      568e5a561ae56e09656bfb99       NaN                1               NaN   
4      568df45a177e30c6487d3600         1                1                 1   

   main-rating  thank-you  
0            2        NaN  
1            1          1  
2            1        NaN  
3            1        NaN  
4            1          1
```

EDIT:

There is still problems with `NaN` with joining.
Solution is replace `NaN` to empty `dictionary` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then create `Dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame([[1,  {'name':'Jack','email':'abc'} ], 
                     [2, np.nan],
                     [3,  {'name':'Ram','email':'xyz'}  ],
                     ], columns=['_id','page_view_count'])

print df[df['page_view_count'].isnull()].index
#Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')

print pd.Series([{}], index=df[df['page_view_count'].isnull()].index , name='page_view_count')
#1    {}
#Name: page_view_count, dtype: object

df['page_view_count'] = df['page_view_count'].fillna(pd.Series([{}], index=df[df['page_view_count'].isnull()].index , name='page_view_count'))
print df
#   _id                       page_view_count
#0    1  {u'name': u'Jack', u'email': u'abc'}
#1    2                                    {}
#2    3   {u'name': u'Ram', u'email': u'xyz'}


df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['page_view_count']]).join(df['_id'], how='right')
df1 = df1.sort_index(1)
print df1
#   _id email  name
#0    1   abc  Jack
#1    2   NaN   NaN
#2    3   xyz   Ram
```

Comment: getting this AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: it is dictionary type `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: `key` is there for every row but somewhere page_view_count is `nan`

Comment: You can try omit these rows : `df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['page_view_count'] if type(x) != np.float] ).join(df['_id'])
`

Comment: One issue is there if in some row page_view_count is `NaN` then it is giving wrong values.

Comment: Hmmm, edit doesnt work? Because `type(x) != np.float` will be filtering `NaN`, because `NaN` are float.

Comment: Can you check `types` of `nan`? Try `print type(df.loc[2, 'page_view_count'])`, `2` is value of index of row, where is `nan` in `page_view_count`. Maybe it is `string`, not `float`

Comment: Or you can try check all `types` of column `page_view_count` by `print [type(x) for x in df['page_view_count']]`

Comment: give me few minutes...I'm in meeting

Comment: No problem, I am waiting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102671/discussion-between-imsonugupta-and-jezrael).