# Remap values-dict to columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I have a dataframe where values of `features`-column are dict-like as here:

http://screencast.com/t/0Ko0NIBLwo

```
   features                    name             price  rating  read reviews
9  {'Cooking...': '- S...', }  Master Chef...  $279.99   None  None      {}
```

example of dict:

```
{u'Cooking Type': u'- Specialty Cooking', u'Cooking Area': u'- Backyard', u'Brand Name': u'- Pizzacraft', u'Fuel Type': u'- Propane', u'Product Type': u'- BBQ', u'Size': u'- Medium Size'}
```

Does it possible to transform these values to new columns like?

```
   features                    Cooking Type       Specialty Cooking  ... name             price  rating  read reviews
9  {'Cooking...': '- S...', }  Specialty Cooking   Backyard          ... Master Chef...    $279.99   None  None      {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print df
                                            features          name    price  \
0  {u'Cooking Type': u'- Specialty Cooking', u'Co...  Master Chef1  $279.99   
1  {u'Cooking Type': u'- Specialty Cooking', u'Co...  Master Chef3  $279.99   

  rating  read reviews  
0   None  None      {}  
1   None  None      {}  

df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['features']], index=df.index)

for col in df1.columns:
    df1[col] = df1[col].str.replace(r'-','').str.strip()

print df1
   Brand Name Cooking Area       Cooking Type Fuel Type Product Type  \
0  Pizzacraft     Backyard  Specialty Cooking   Propane          BBQ   
1  Pizzacraft     Backyard  Specialty Cooking   Propane          BBQ   

          Size  
0  Medium Size  
1  Medium Size  

df = pd.concat([df1, df[['name','price','rating','read','reviews']]], axis=1)
print df
   Brand Name Cooking Area       Cooking Type Fuel Type Product Type  \
0  Pizzacraft     Backyard  Specialty Cooking   Propane          BBQ   
1  Pizzacraft     Backyard  Specialty Cooking   Propane          BBQ   

          Size          name    price rating  read reviews  
0  Medium Size  Master Chef1  $279.99   None  None      {}  
1  Medium Size  Master Chef3  $279.99   None  None      {}
```

Comment: How can I struggle with `NaN` and `{}` values? `df1 = pd.DataFrame([x for x in df['FEATURES'] if isinstance(x, dict) and x], index=df.index)` raised an error *ValueError: Shape of passed values is (17, 66), indices imply (17, 105)*

Comment: Yes, it is problem. One solution is replace `NaN` to `{}` - [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34991815/2901002)