# Pandas: How to group by column values when column values are dicts?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I am doing an exercise in which the current requirement is to "Find the top 10 major project themes (using column 'mjtheme_namecode')".

My first thought was to do `group_by`, then count and sort the groups.

However, the values in this column are lists of dicts, e.g.

```
[{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},
 {'code': '6', 'name': 'Social protection and risk management'}]
```

and I can't (apparently) group these, at least not with `group_by`. I get an error.

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Is there a trick? I'm guessing something along the lines of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628640/remap-values-dict-to-columns-in-pandas).

(I can group by another column that has string values and matches 1:1 with this column, but the exercise is specific.)

`df.head()`
[image: dataframe, 10 records]

Comment: are you able to show your sample output? usually you would pass the dict/json into another dataframe to expand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flattening nested Json in pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795561/flattening-nested-json-in-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to solve your problem:

**Using `pandas==0.25`**

1. Flatten the list of dict
2. Transform dict in columns:

**Step 1**

```py
df = df.explode('mjtheme_namecode')
```

**Step 2**

```py
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['mjtheme_namecode'].values.tolist())
```

**Added**: if the dict has multiple hierarchies, you can try using `json_normalize`:

```py
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = df.join(json_normalize(df['mjtheme_namecode'].values.tolist())
```

The only issue here is pd.explode will duplicate all other columns (in case that is an issue).

**Using sample data**:

```py
x = [
    [1,2,[{'a':1, 'b':3},{'a':2, 'b':4}]],
    [1,3,[{'a':5, 'b':6},{'a':7, 'b':8}]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

Out[1]:
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       2      [{'a': 1, 'b': 3}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
1   1       3      [{'a': 5, 'b': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8}]


## Step 1
df.explode('col3')
Out[2]:
    col1    col2    col3
0   1        2      {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
0   1        2      {'a': 2, 'b': 4}
1   1        3      {'a': 5, 'b': 6}
1   1        3      {'a': 7, 'b': 8}

## Step 2
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['col3'].values.tolist()))
Out[3]:

    col1    col2    col3                a   b
0   1       2      {'a': 1, 'b': 3}     1   3
0   1       2      {'a': 2, 'b': 4}     1   3
1   1       3      {'a': 5, 'b': 6}     2   4
1   1       3      {'a': 7, 'b': 8}     2   4

## Now you can group with the new variables
```